# How to rollback mistyped migration in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

I have created a migration using the command

```
php artisan make:migration create_members_table.php --create=members
```

So it created a class name `CreateMembersTable.php` including `.`. Now I want to rollback it and to correct the class name.

```
php artisan migrate:rollback --step=1
```

and I see this error as expected:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError] 
>    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '{'

**OR**

In order Laravel not to notice if I delete the file manually, how to do it?

Comment: rollback before you change the migration file..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just delete the file and create a new one. Rollbacks are used for database not the migration files itself.

Or you can rename the file and the class name and if you get errors running the migration then run `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: For any created migration it adds a row into table "migrations" in MySQL. So I will also have to delete that row?